# Why can't I be summoned in Dark Souls 3?

Tags: xbox-one, xbox-network, dark-souls-3

There was server maintenance done to the game about 2 days ago. I gave my girlfriend my copy of Dark Souls 3 because I also had a digital version and I planned on helping her through the beginning area however ever time she tries to summon me it says failed to join session. We have tried the following things to no avail:

- Restart either Xbox
- Restart either router
- Change covenant
- Move summon sign.

We also tried to see if I could summon her and for me her sign won't even pop up.

A couple of side notes, we are both able to summon other people with ease, and we are able to be in each others parties.

Our setting are:

> Cross-region play: Matchmaking ON
>   Password Matching: DOOM
>   Summon sign visibility: Unrestricted
>   Voice chat: Allowed
>   Player Name Display: Gamertag
>   Launch Setting: Play Online.

**EDIT:** I tried to play with her on another console and it let us play together.

Comment: It sounds like a firewall issue on her end. https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/168545-dark-souls-iii/73672992

Comment: Can you both connect one anothers Xbox Live Party? Party chat is still peer-to-peer i.e. if you can't join a party together @Ben 's comment would be correct

Comment: @Quiet We are able to be in each others party yes

Comment: is your NAT listed as open (both xbox consoles)? and have you tried it without a password to see if it will connect? (not sure if this is an option)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some things to check:

1. Make sure that you are enkindled.
2. Make *sure* that your firewall is not blocking the [appropriate ports](https://support.bandainamcoent.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/512/458/dark-souls-iii---connection-tips-for-dark-souls-iii). This is likely not going to be the case, since you have stated that both of you *can* connect to other players online.
3. Check that you have not been soft banned. You can check this by using the [Way of the White Circlet](http://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Way+of+White+Circlet) (again, this is unlikely due to your ability to connect to other players).
4. Double check you password - *passwords are case sensitive*. So for example if you are using "DOOM", and she is using "Doom", they will not match up.

Also, just to clarify, your covenant does not have any affect on your connection. Additionally, if you are in a "busy" area (e.g. in a common PvP spot), it might take longer to connect properly.

Comment: I have tried all of these things and none of them work

Comment: +1 though, because those are normally the problem